# vbs script works on 86 but fails on 64

Tags: windows, vbscript, x86, 64-bit

the script works on x86 but doesnt create the file on x64.

Can anyone understand why and explain?

The script is searching the registry, Uninstall key and checking for displayname equal to what im searching for, and grabbing the productcode, and saving to a file which then copies to a remote share i have set up.

```
On error resume Next

Dim strName, WshShell, oReg, keyname, WshNetwork, ComputerName

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")

Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8 

ComputerName = WshNetwork.ComputerName
FileName = ComputerName & "_data.txt"
'FileName = "sep_data.txt"

'=============================================
'Chage the value here with DisplayName's value 
strName = "Symantec Endpoint Protection"
'=============================================

'currentDirectory = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName,(Len(WScript.ScriptFullName))-(Len(WScript.ScriptName)))
currentDirectory = "c:\windows\temp\"




'set location in registry we want to get data from
Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & ComputerName & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
oReg.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrSubKeys

'check each key in uninstall for any display name called Symantec Endpoint Protection
For Each subkey In arrSubKeys
    keyname = ""
    keyname = wshshell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\" & subkey & "\DisplayName")
    If keyname = strName then
        i = subkey
    End If



' Writes text to file if it exists
If i Then  


    'open text file for writing
    Set filetxt = fso.OpenTextFile(currentDirectory & FileName, 2, True) 


    'write to text file 
    filetxt.WriteLine "" & computerName & "," & i & ""


    'Close file
    filetxt.Close 

    'Copy file to network share
    fso.CopyFile "c:\windows\temp\" & FileName & "", "\\hostname\test\", true


End If
Next

Set WshShell = Nothing
Set ObjReg = Nothing
Set computerName = Nothing
Set i = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

Comment: `Next` is missing, please fix the code, or paste the entire script. You may try to call `CheckOSx86x64Args` at the first line of the script, like [here](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/fb.ashx?m=108289)

Comment: fixed, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Delete "on error resume next", now you can find out why.

Comment: I will try that now, thank you Hans! Update to follow

Comment: i see its having some problems with reading certain subkeys which is fine. im really only targetting 1 key that i know has read access. What else can i  try ?

Comment: @32or64 it will likely be permissions, new servers have UAC enabled by default which means even logged on as an Administrator *(not the actual Administrator account)* means you are still beholden to the dreaded *"Admin Approval mode"* which roughly translates as the scripts will not run as elevated unless you explicitly call them as such.

Comment: if i manually copy the file to the machine and double click it, it is doing everything its supposed to do. If i run it via deployment tool or run it via exe i create, it doesnt work. i can bypass UAC via our deployment tool or packaging.

Comment: Then your deployment tool is correctly elevating the process before calling the script. Have you tried something like [`psexec` by the SysInternals team](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553), it's by far the best remote execution tool I've ever used.

Comment: figured out part of the issue, i needed to specify to use the 64bit registry in my reg query call. 1 issue down, 1 to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used an alternative method to move the file to a share. why the 64 bit os was getting missed was due to my reg query call. it was missing /reg64 at the end.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can find *why* (in short there are separate structures for 32 and 64 bits in the registry and the file system access is redirected)

For a *how*, if the application/registry is 32 bit, start the script using the 32 bit script host version (in 64b OS versions, the 32b executables are under `%systemroot%\SysWOW64`)

```
"%systemroot%\SysWOW64\cscript.exe" myscript.vbs
```

The inverse problem, you have a 32 bits process but you need to access the 64 bit registry, requires the start of a 64 bit process, and here things change.

While the executables in `%systemroot%\System32` are 64 bits, as the current process is 32 bits it is running under a registry and file system redirection and any reference to `%systemroot%\System32` in converted to a reference to `%systemroot%\SysWOW64` (32bit processes expect a 32bit OS). This can be solved using

```
"%systemroot%\sysnative\cscript.exe" myscript.vbs
```

Yes, if you search the `sysnative` folder from a 64 bit process you will not find it, but from a 32 bit process it gives you access to the 64 bit `system32` folder.

**edited** to include a workaround. The basic idea is to try to find the required information using the current engine. If not found, the script relaunches itself with a different host.

```
Option Explicit 

Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

Const ForReading = 1 _ 
    , ForWriting = 2 _ 
    , ForAppending = 8 

Const UNINSTALL_KEY_PATH = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
Const KEY_DISPLAY_NAME = "Symantec Endpoint Protection"
Const TARGET_FOLDER = "C:\TEMP"
Const ARGUMENT_FLAG = "_CHILD_"

Dim shell
    Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim retValue, alternateHost
    If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists(ARGUMENT_FLAG) Then 
        retValue = shell.Run( quote(WScript.FullName) & " " & quote(WScript.ScriptFullName) & " /" & ARGUMENT_FLAG, 0, True )
        If retValue > 0 Then 
            With WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                If .GetFile( WScript.FullName ).ParentFolder.Name = "SysWOW64" Then 
                    alternateHost = "\sysnative\"
                Else 
                    alternateHost = "\SysWOW64\"
                End If 
                alternateHost = .BuildPath( shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%systemroot%") & alternateHost, "cscript.exe" )
                If .FileExists( alternateHost ) Then 
                    Call shell.Run( quote(alternateHost) & " " & quote(WScript.ScriptFullName) & " /" & ARGUMENT_FLAG, 0, True )
                End If 
            End With 
        End If 
        WScript.Quit
    End If 

Dim reg    
    Set reg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")

Dim subKeys, subKey, value, keyFound
    keyFound = False
    reg.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, UNINSTALL_KEY_PATH, subKeys
    For Each subKey In subKeys
        reg.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, UNINSTALL_KEY_PATH & "\" & subkey , "DisplayName", value
        If Not IsNull( value ) Then 
            If value = KEY_DISPLAY_NAME Then 
                keyFound = True
                Exit For
            End If 
        End If 
    Next 

Dim computerName, baseName, fileName, exitCode
    If keyFound Then 
        computerName = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network").ComputerName
        baseName = computerName & "_data.txt"
        With WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            fileName = .BuildPath( shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%temp%"), baseName ) 
            .CreateTextFile( fileName, True ).WriteLine( computerName & "," & KEY_DISPLAY_NAME )
            .CopyFile fileName, .BuildPath( TARGET_FOLDER, .GetFile( fileName ).Name )
        End With 
        exitCode = 0
    Else 
        exitCode = 1
    End If 

    Call WScript.Quit( exitCode )

Function quote( text ) 
    quote = """" & text & """"
End Function
```

Comment: i ran as advised but it still doesn't work in 64 bit. If i double click on my the vbs file, it works, but i run it via SCCM or DesktopCentral or via EXE/MSI, it fails. Weird issue for sure.

Comment: @32or64 then your problem could be just the inverse. Try with `"%windir%\sysnative\cscript.exe" myscript.vbs`

Comment: Checking on that shortly.. Update to follow

Comment: `sysnative`? That's a new one on me, I'd usually just go with `%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe`.

Comment: @Lankymart, under file system redirection, a 32 bit process will not see the real 64 bit `system32`. Requests for `system32` are redirected to `SysWoW64`

Comment: "%windir%\SysWow64\cscript.exe" myvbscript.vbs is not working. The file doesnt get created. But if i just copy of the vbs file and double click, it does  create the file, write to it and copy it to my file share.

Comment: Also to MC ND, i dont have the sysnative folder since im running my OS via VM. i only have the syswow64.

Comment: @32or64, you can not see the `sysnative` folder from a 64 bit process. It is only visible from a 32 bit process to be able to reach the native 64bit system32 folder.

Comment: i was infact able to run it using sysnative, but that still didnt work either. im trying different combo using 32bit cmd to call 32bit cscript, 32bit cmd to call 64bit cscript etc etc, doesnt matter what combo i try, its not working. It only works if i double click on the file to run it. If you can think of any other suggestions, it will be most welcome. i wish i could just write this in powershell, would take 2 minutes but most of our servers dont have it enabled, since im dealing with legacy app servers (NT, 2000, 2003). Thanks for your help along this way MC ND!

Comment: @32or64 which servers is it failing on? Newer ones will likely have UAC enabled which means your scripts will not run as elevated by default even if logged in as an Administrator.

Comment: on x64 it does not write the productcode into the file and it also does not copy over. on x86 it is writing the product code but is also not copying over to the file share. This is happening weather i run it on 7,8,10 or 2003,2008,2012. Try copying the code and running it and see for yourself, if you want.

Comment: @32or64, I've included a workaround for 32/64 bit, BUT as far as I know (what the documentation says), the wmi registry provider is only available from Windows Vista.

Comment: @MC ND, Thanks for posting the work around, let me check on it and report back